# Study abroad in Hong Kong, should I start learning traditional?

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters, traditional-vs-simplified

I am currently learning Mandarin and simplified characters, but as I am studying abroad in Hong Kong next year, should I start learning traditional characters? Or are simplified characters widespread enough now that I should continue focusing on simplified?

I am in my second year of study at university. I will be taking a Cantonese course when I study abroad in addition to a Mandarin course. I will not be studying abroad until the Fall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> simplified characters widespread enough

They're not. Most, if not all, road signs, newspapers are in traditional Chinese, and English.

Web sites are in traditional, simplified Chinese and English.

I would recommend learning traditional Chinese, not for surviving in HK. It's the culture, the literature of yore are recorded in this script. If you need to study further, you need to know it.

By the way, if you know it, you may compare the difference between Taiwan, Hong Kong, Macau and "that area".

Lastly, learning Cantonese and Mandarin together, well, good luck lah :)

Comment: Lastly lastly, learning Traditional and Simplified characters together and compare the differences.